# The undo button in SageMaker Studio clears cell's output

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I run a cell in SageMaker Studio:

[image: run cell]

And then I click <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to undo, but the cell's output gets deleted:

[image: output removed]

In the **Edit** menu there are 2 types of undos:

1. Undo <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>
2. Undo Cell Operation <kbd>Z</kbd>

[image: edit menu]

The first option **(Undo)** deletes the output as well (like the shortcut does), and although I'm not sure how to use the shortcut for the second option **(Undo Cell Operation)**, since it says just <kbd>Z</kbd>, I tried clicking it and it simply removed the newly created cell, which is not the kind of undo that I need.

That being said, if I head over to `Settings > Advanced Settings Editor`, there's a note that says:

> // Experimental settings to enable the undo/redo on the notebook document level.
> // Disable the undo/redo on the notebook document level, so actions independent cells can have their own history. **The undo/redo never applies on the outputs, in other words, outputs don't have history.** A moved cell completely looses history capability for now.
> `"experimentalDisableDocumentWideUndoRedo": false,`

So it's strange that the exact opposite of what they state happens.

I also tried enabling the `experimentalDisableDocumentWideUndoRedo` setting, but that just made the <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> shortcut act like a Cell-Operation undo (i.e. removes newly created cells etc.).

Any idea how to stop the regular <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> shortcut from clearing the cell's output?

Comment: I'm unable to see this behavior - cmd+Z seems to undo what I typed in Studio cells and the output still remains (same as vanilla Jupyterlab). Can you share your JupyterLab version?

Comment: @durga_sury - Version 3.6.1

Comment: I'm using the same version on Studio, and can't seem to replicate this.